# In Jenkins, how can I specify which folders get checked out of my trunk in the "Source Code Management" section?

Tags: svn, jenkins, svn-trunk

I’m using Jenkins 1.651.1 running on JBoss 7.1.3.as.final.

I have a Maven job configured to use SVN.
In my Source Code Management section, I have selected "`Subversion`" which is our source code repository.

In the repository URL section, I have entered my trunk URL, but is there a way I can specify that only certain folders within the trunk get checked out?

Answer (score 1):

You can just enter a URL to a subfolder within your repository.

E.g.

`http://my.subversionurl.com/trunk/some/other/path`

would check out the `/some/other/path` directory

TO add multiple repositories click the Add Module... button and then add multiple repository paths as mentioned above.

You'll also need to set the local module directory to the corresponding sub directory of each to make sure each checked out folder goes into its own subfolder.

Comment: Yeah but I want multiple folders, not just one.  I want folders A, B, and C, but don't want folders D, E, and F.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah got ya, Ive updated the answer with details on how to checkout multiple repositories

Answer (score 0):

Do your setup [advanced behavior](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+plugin+2.0+beta+testing).

Your can define which folders will be monitored.

Comment: Does this plugin only apply to Git?  I'm using SVN.